# I want to change array of struct from fixed to dynamic where as when I remove argument from array compiler throws error

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, go-ethereum

pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Signature{

```
struct signature {
    string value;
    uint rate;
    address sender_acc;
    
}

signature[5] public unverified_sig; // struct array is fixed but I want dynamic, if i del 5 then it 
                                    //gives error  mentioned in the end


function add_signature(string rec_signature) public {
    unverified_sig[0].sender_acc=msg.sender;
    unverified_sig[0].value=rec_signature;
    unverified_sig[0].rate=0;
}
```

}

Output Error:
transact to Signature.add_signature errored: VM error: invalid opcode. invalid opcode The execution might have thrown. Debug the transaction to get more information.

> 

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Solidity do you use? I compiled with `0.5.0` in Remix. There isn't any problem with the dynamic array of struct. But there is a warning about the gas cost of the function that is too high which will exceed the gas limit.

> Gas requirement of function Storage.add_signature is infinite: If the
> gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it
> cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions
> that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying
> arrays in storage)

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.4.17;